# In C, how to set an unsigned char array from argv

Tags: c

In the code below, I would like to have the value of myvar be provided by a program argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    const unsigned char myvar[] = "myvalue";
    return 0;
}
```

How would I get myvar to contain the value of the string from argv[1]?

Comment: Does it *have* to be an array? Can't it simply be a pointer? Considering that you use `const` to make the array constant, there's no real benefit from using an array compared to a pointer in this case.

Comment: I am passing the value to a blowfish encryption function, which expects the unsigned char array.

Comment: And when you pass the array, it will decay to a pointer to its first element anyway, so what will be passed is `unsigned char *`. So no need for the array at all.

Comment: From your comment this is clearly an [X-Y](http://xyproblem.info/) - you should ask about passing command line arguments to the blowfish function.  e.g. `Blowfish_encrypt( state, (unsigned char *)argv[1], output ) ;`  In fact even the type cast is probably unnecessary as `char*` will be implicitly cast to `unsigned char*`.

Comment: Is this value the encryption key or the data to encrypt?  This matters because the key can be a variable size, but the data is a fixed size.

Comment: `unsigned char myvar[strlen(argv[1]) + 1]; strcpy(myvar, argv[1]);` might be a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only reading, then you can simply copy the address of `argv[1]` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    const unsigned char *myvar = NULL;

    // Be sure to check argc first
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough arguments.\n");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    myvar = (const unsigned char *)argv[1];

    printf("myvar = %s\n", myvar);
}
```

If you want to change `myvar` then you should copy the string with `strncpy` or alike.

Comment: @chux I concur.

Answer (score 0):

An array cannot be initialized by a pointer or by another array.  You can only initialize it with an initializer list or (in the char of a `char` array) a string constant.

What you can do it copy the contents of another string with `strcpy`.  And since you'll be using this array as a parameter to an encryption function, it will probably need to be a fixed size.

```
char myvar[8] = { 0 };        // initialize all values to 0
strncpy(myvar, argv[1], 8);   // copy the first 8 bytes
```